# Help Interpreting Ultraviolet Photoelectron Spectroscopy (UPS) data

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, data-analysis

I was given a batch of UPS data without any background other than the materials examined and I don't have any experiencing interpreting it.  I wanted to reach out to some experts (hopefully, someone here) as to reading materials as to how to interpret this data.  To be clear, I don't need a theoretical explanation of how UPS works - I understand that, I need a tutorial into how to bend this raw data into a form that can actually lend me some insight into my samples.

I was given 3 files per sample.

1. What I think is the main file as it has "Sample_Name He1 UPS" as its title.  A weird thing: even though it says He1 (21.2 eV), inside the file it says "Photon energy: 40.8 eV".
2. A calibration file that uses silver titled: "Sample_Name He1 Ag Calibration 6V".  Again, inside the file it says the photon energy is 40.8 eV.
3. A file called "He1 Ag Fermi Edge"

So it seems fairly clear that I am supposed to use the data from the second and third files and maybe the photon energy to process the data in the first file.  My question is, how?  I need some experimentalists to lend a hand!
Thanks

Comment: You *need* to know the origin of the conflicting energies and which represents the real experimental conditions. Do you have the code that generates the files? Could the 40.8 be a default that just isn't getting set properly.

Comment: As an aside, using filenames or pathnames to store metadata is *always* a temptation but rarely a good idea.

Comment: I was basically just given this data, so I suspect that was why the metadata was in the header.  In addition, I know this about the conditions:  Scans were done with a pass energy of 2.95 eV and 0.025 eV/step with an HeI transition and referenced with Ag and a 6V bias.  Will this help towards processing this data?

Comment: Quick search tells that 40.8 eV photons are emitted by $\rm HeII$, which is $He^+$.